# Stuck with code using if statements

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, do-while

This might be a non-sense question, but i'm kind of stuck so I was wondering if someone can help. I have the following code:

```
bool while_condition=false;

do{

   if(/*condition*/){
      //code
   }
   else if(/*condition*/){
      //code
   }
   else if(/*condition*/){
      //code
   }
   ...//some more else if
   else{
      //code
   }

   check_for_do_while_loop(while_condition, /*other parameters*/);

}while(while_condition);
```

the various `if` and `else if` exclude with each other but each have other `if` inside; if a certain condition is met (which can't be specified in a single if statement), then the code return a value and the `do while` loop is ended. But if, after entering a single `else if`, the conditions inside aren't met the code exit without actually doing nothing, and the while loop restart the whole.

I want the program to remember where he entered and avoid that part of the code, i.e. to avoid that specific `else if` he entered without any result, so he can try entering another `else if`. I thought about associating a boolean to the statements but I'm not quite sure on how to do it. Is there a way which allows me not to modify the code structure too much?

Comment: Smells like [Chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

Comment: Add variables that indicate which branches you've taken, set them in these branches, and use them in your `if` conditions.

Comment: Why can't the condition be specified in a single if statement?

Comment: @VaughnCato This is an extract from a longer code, there are various condition i have to check using `for` loops and other things but i don't want to do it before knowing they can actually be useful.

Comment: @MohitJain I thought about that but it's the last thing i'll try, i want to know if there's a better way without hard-coding it

Comment: Couldn't you extract the complex logic into a separate function which returns a bool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give an idea of one way of approaching this that avoid loads of variables, here is an outline of how you might data-drive a solution.

```
class TestItem
{
public:
    typedef bool (*TestFuncDef)(const state_type& state_to_test, std::shared_ptr<result_type>& result_ptr);
    TestItem(TestFuncDef test_fn_parm)
    {
        test_fn = test_fn_parm;
        already_invoked = false;
    }

    bool Invoke(const state_type& state_to_test, std::shared_ptr<result_type>& result_ptr)
    {
        already_invoked = true;
        return test_fn(state_to_test, result_ptr);
    }

    bool AlreadyInvoked() const {return already_invoked; }
private:
    TestFuncDef test_fn;
    bool already_invoked;
};


std::shared_ptr<result_type> RunTest(std::list<TestItem>& test_item_list, state_type& state_to_test)
{
    for(;;) {
        bool made_a_test = false;
        for (TestItem& item : test_item_list) {
            std::shared_ptr<result_type> result_ptr;
            if (!item.AlreadyInvoked()) {
                made_a_test = true;
                if (item.Invoke(state_to_test, result_ptr)) {
                    return result_ptr;
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }
        if (!made_a_test)
            throw appropriate_exception("No conditions were matched");
    }
}
```

This is not supposed to be a full solution to your problem but suggests another way of approaching it.

The important step not documented here is to build up the std::list of TestItems to be passed to RunTest. Code to do so might look like this

```
    std::list<TestItem> test_item_list;
    test_item_list.push_back(TestItem(ConditionFn1));
    test_item_list.push_back(TestItem(ConditionFn2));
```

The definition of ConditionFn1 might look something like

```
bool ConditionFn1(const state_type& state_to_test, std::shared_ptr<result_type>& result_ptr)
{
    // Do some work
    if (....)
        return false;
    else {
        result_ptr.reset(new result_type(some_args));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the only way of data-driving a solution. You could use functor objects rather than condition functions, etc.